# Need some advice on a Javascript number guessing game

Tags: javascript

this is my first post ever so go easy on me haha! I'm working on a number game that prompts a user to guess a random number between 1 and 100. The part I'm having trouble with is telling a user if they previously already guessed a number. I've been playing around with it myself and for example if I submit 10, and then 10 again it will say that I repeated a guess (which is what it should do). If I say 10 for a third time it doesn't tell me that I've repeated a guess and rather that the number is too low (it should just say that I've repeated the guess again). Here's the jsfiddle for clarification: https://jsfiddle.net/k1d8awf6/2/.

```
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
var guessList = new Array();

var guess = prompt("Hello user, I'm thinking of a number between 1-100. What is it?");
guessList.push(guess);

while (guess != random) {    
    for (i = 0; i < guessList.length-1; i++) {
        if (guess == guessList[i]) {
        guess = prompt("You already guessed this number. Try again.");     
        }
    }
    if (guess > random) {
        guess = prompt("Your guess is too high! Try again.");
        guessList.push(guess);
    }
    if (guess < random) {
        guess = prompt("Your guess is too low! Try again.");
        guessList.push(guess);
    }
    if (guess == random) {
       alert("Nice job! You guessed the correct number! It took you " + guessList.length + " tries!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you're prompting the user for every previous guess, take out the `prompt()` call from the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing if's, when you should be doing else if's. In addition, you can use the indexOf function instead of looping through elements.  eg:

```
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
var guessList = new Array();

var guess = prompt("Hello user, I'm thinking of a number between 1-100. What is it?");
while (guess != random) {
    if (!guess) {
        // The user cancelled or entered 0, just cancel the game
        return;
    } else if (guessList.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
        // User already guessed this number
        guess = prompt("You already guessed this number. Try again.");
    } else {
        // User hasn't guessed this number, store their guess then display whether they're too high or too low
        guessList.push(guess);

        if (guess > random) {
            guess = prompt("Your guess is too high! Try again.");
        } else if (guess < random) {
            guess = prompt("Your guess is too low! Try again.");
        }
    } 
}

// The guess is correct when we exit the loop
alert("Nice job! You guessed the correct number! It took you " + (guessList.length + 1) + " tries!");
```

More info on indexOf: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

You may also want to end the game if the user enters '0' or Cancels the dialog :)

**Edit**

Edited to fix some logic errors, updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k1d8awf6/8/

Comment: Is there a reason why it won't run on jsfiddle when I change the if's to else if's?

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure how to end the game. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I did not run it - I see a couple errors, updating now :)

Comment: Thank you so much mofojed, that makes a lot of sense! :)